# Radiator is getting more heated

Tags: radiator

my indica vista car engine is getting over heated. Is this because of not mixing water and usind only coolant oil, if so what should i doo now can i mix water now in that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can't just use pure coolant in a radiator.   The coolant raises the boiling point of water, but without water it will not work well.

Replace the coolant in your system with the correct mixture of water and coolant.

Answer (score 1):

Water has a boiling point of 100c/212f at sea level. A soloution of 67% antifreeze to 33% water raises the boiling point of the mixture to 113C/235F. A mixture of 50/50 will cover most vehicles except for really cold climatic areas of the world. Anything less than around 40% antifreeze solution will allow cavitation of the water and corrosion of most of the metals inside the engine. Most commercially supplied 'coolant' is antifreeze with distilled water, and is not some magic fluid. There are five main antifreezes: **Ethylene glycol**- Most used by most car manufacturers POISONOUS, **Propylene glycol** - Considered to be less harmful as it is non poisonous. Found in windsceen washes, **Phosphate free**, recommended by some car manufacturers as being phosphate free makes it more eco friendly, **Organic Acid Technology(OAT)** - no phosphates no silicons and used in all late model GM vehicles, **Hybrid OAT** has an additive to be less abrasive to water pumps.